# How to get tr tag to have gradient and rounded corners?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table and the 1st upper `<tr>` with a simple gradient #ffffff -> #dddddd

Is there any way I can have rounded borders on the table using css?

It rounds the borders now, but because of the `<TR class='my_gradient'>` it sticks two sharp corners in the upper part of the table. How can I make those sharp corner round?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the relevant code you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your border radius to the table instead and hide any overflow to snip the corners of the gradient off:

```
table{
       -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/02c74u98/1/)

Comment: thanks! it works! i was not aware of the insides of overflow : hidden function. next time i'll read more docs :) thanks man, really appreciate it

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped (: